# Create user designed application in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need to create a prg. in that user can designed the form based on their requirements (like add delete buttons, textbox, labels, change its properties, location) and save the form changes permanently.
  Please guide me.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific if you want meaningful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Are the buttons etc. to be entirely dynamic, or are they from a predefined set of commands? Cause if it's the first requirement, then I'd suggest just deploying visual studio...

Comment: Actually i need to store 10 fields for a client. If the no of fields differ from this for a new client i have to create a new project. Instead of create a new project i want create prg. in that user can made changes as per their requirements. The function was just store the fields in db.

Answer (score 0):

[Noooo! You'll put us all out of work!](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Inner-Platform_Effect.aspx)